# How to run multiple AWS CodePipelines in order?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-codepipeline

I have an AWS environment with 3 CodePipelines. Let's call those- P1, P2 and P3. I'd like to run those in "specific" sequence. That sequence will be determined by a Lambda function.

This Lambda function does some calculation, and determine which sequence the pipelines need to be run. So, it could be-

```
P1 > P2 > P3

P3 > P2 > P1

P2 > P3 > P1
```

Each codepipeline must finish successfully before the next one is run. How can I achieve this?

At first I tried to do it using that same Lambda function, but it has 15 mins timeout. We don't know how long each pipeline's gonna take. All together they could take even ~30 mins.

Also, since the sequence is dynamic, I couldn't just get one pipeline to export a file to S3, and use that as one of source for another one!

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally EventBridge would do the trick (as mentioned by @Marcin), however, it didn't work with my particular scenario.

I resolved the issue by introducing "Step Function" between the Lambda function and pipelines.

Lambda function passes some parameter to the Step Function. Based on that, it takes different path (different order of pipeline to execute)

Also, it has "wait" mechanism, as well as, GetPipelineExecution to check status. Together they ensure that one pipeline needs to end successfully before the next one is triggered.

Hope this helps someone in future :)

Answer (score 1):

CP [emits events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/detect-state-changes-cloudwatch-events.html) using EventBridge. Thus you would have to use that.

Basically, you would setup **event rules** which would trigger executions of subsequent pipeline, based on successful completion of previous pipeline.

Comment: Thank you for your response. How would EventBridge know- which one is the next pipeline? Let's say- when P1 is finished successfully, an EB rule is triggered. How will it know whether to run P2 or P3? At this stage, only the Lambda function I mentioned calculates that.
I feel this whole thing is tricky because the CP order is dynamic!

Comment: @AladdinKnight If you require complex logic, the event bridge rule would trigger a lambda function. The function would then decide what to trigger next.

Comment: @AladdinKnight How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?